# Как правильно в Laravel создать helper функции

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel

Хочу создать функцию в *Laravel*, для дальнейшего использования, 
в интернете есть много информации, но есть и различия, в частности, 
  по вопросу *создания функции* и *директории файла*.

В официальной документации не нашел рекомендации по этому вопросу.

Как  *правильно* **создать функцию helper** и **в какую папку положить** ?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в composer.json, в раздел autoload, подраздел files, чтобы получилось примерно такое содержание:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
    "app/helpers.php"
,
"classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

далее

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Далее создавайте ваши функции в файле app/helpers.php